# How to read a float value from Sql database using datareader?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read the sql database table which consists of both integer and float values. I am having a problem in reading float value. I have tried to parse but i get error.  Below is my code:

```
 private void PopulateFields()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = *** ; Initial Catalog = abc123; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = xyz12; Password = xyz12"))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  Machine_name, turn_right, turn_left, total, End_time_sec FROM  Machine_status", con);

            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string MachineName = myReader["Machine_name"].ToString();                                  
                float Total = float.Parse(myReader["Total"].ToString());  
                float TurnRight = float.Parse(myReader["Turn_right"].ToString());
                float TurnLeft = float.Parse(myReader["Turn_left"].ToString());
                float Total_1= float.Parse(myReader["Turn_right + Turn_left"].ToString());
                TextBox1.Text = (myReader["End_time_sec"].ToString());
                Chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
                Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
                Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(MachineName,Total_1);
                Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(MachineName, Total-Total_1);  
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

[image: Progress chart]
I am trying to have a progress chart with the `machineName` in X-axis and in Y-axis represents `Total`, `Total_1`. Where `Total_1` shows the job done.
Details:

```
Machine_name = abc ;
turn_right = 2.5; 
turn_left = 3.2 ; 
total = 9; 
Total_1 = 5.7
```

Please help!!

Comment: Where does your `reader` variable come from? I've seen the declaration for `myReader`, but none for `reader`. Also did you try to see what you get with `myReader["Total"]` without any `.ToString()` and `float.Parse`? Last but not least, you wrote about an error you got, so can you copy/paste it in your question?

Comment: Sorry about "reader". I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetFloat method.  The number is the index position of the column.

```
float total = reader.GetFloat(3);
```

Comment: this is also invalid by the way - float Total_1= float.Parse(reader["Turn_right + Turn_left"].ToString());